# Is it possible to remove route from swagger ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

Is it possible to hide Url for swagger ui. I have make app from swagger editor. its totaly work with yaml file. i am unble to to it in swagger.yaml file.
Tried "x-hidden", "x-visibility" and read docs on swagger.

Tried chatGPT, Bard and docs and stackoverflow.